# Travis-CI stopped building Github project

Tags: github, travis-ci

After my last failed build:

https://travis-ci.org/acgetchell/CDT-plusplus

Travis-CI is no longer building newer versions (there have been at least 4 commits since then).

https://github.com/acgetchell/CDT-plusplus/commits/master

I've run travis monitor in the background:

```
─[adam][hapkido][~]
└─▪ travis monitor -r acgetchell/CDT-plusplus

Monitoring acgetchell/CDT-plusplus:
```

And latest git push doesn't show any events.

Edit: It passes travis-lint.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your config file 'corrupt' - if it has errors then travis won't make a build. Check it's indentation, and also the requests section of your project on travis (accessible from settings), it will tell you why your build didn't start.